# How to install 2X Client on 64-bit ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 64-bit

Installed it with .deb from 2X website. Now got:

```
> /opt/2X/Client/bin/2XClient: error while loading shared libraries: libXpm.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to google for this problem but no luck (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ruby-rvm/+bug/894311)

Comment: try searching for the file with apt-file.

Comment: OK.

# apt-file search libXpm.so.4

libxpm4: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4

libxpm4: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4.11.0

libxpm4-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4.11.0

Comment: Where did you find a 64bit .deb for this? How did you manage to install it? According to their website: `The 2X Client is also approved for the following 32-bit Linux distributions: Ubuntu 8.04, Ubuntu 8.10, Ubuntu 9.04, Ubuntu 9.10, OpenSuse 11.1, Fedora Core 9, Fedora Core 11, CentOs 5.2, VectorLinux 6.0.` so there does not seem to be a 64bit client available.

Comment: OK. My question then is: how to install 2XClient on 64-bit ubuntu?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package

Comment: So you first install the application, and then the libraries it needs. With apt-file, you get to know what packages you have to install (32 bit versions!). Then ... it should work.

Comment: Well, it does not. And that forum thread does not help either.

Comment: What do you mean by does not help? How far you got? Only this libXpm.so.4 missing? Did you install "libxpm4"?

Answer (score 2):

This is my first post ever, so let me know when it´s useful to you.

This package seams to be i386 specific, with no amd64 version available. 
Apparently linux system can cope with packages meant for different architectures using e.g. multiarch (ubuntu 11+).
This is how I installed a working version of 2xclient in the Terminal on my Linux Mint 15 64 bit.

1. Download the appropriate package from www.2x.com
2. tell the system to accept i386 packages

   ```
   sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
   ```
3. update the available packages from repositories

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. install the downloaded package (go to the directory first)

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i 2XClient.deb
   ```
5. You may need to fix broken dependencies using apt-get (didn´t do anything in my case)

   ```
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```
6. Check which files where installed from the package

   ```
   sudo dpkg -L '2xclient'
   ```
7. View the library dependencies of the binary, in my case as follows

   ```
   ldd /opt/2X/Client/bin/2XClient
   ```

   in my case the missing dependencies are 2 files: libxml2.so.2 and libXpm.so.4
8. Find the packages that own these missing files

   ```
   sudo dpkg -S 'libXpm.so.4'
   sudo dpkg -S 'libxml2.so.2'
   ```

   which resulted in the information below:

   file           package

   libxml2.so.2   libxml2     :amd64

   libXpm.so.4    libxpm4     :amd64
9. Install the packages containing the missing files, with a explicit architecture reference (i386)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libxpm4:i386
   sudo apt-get install libxml2:i386
   ```
10. check your dependencies again

    ldd /opt/2X/Client/bin/2XClient
11. Start up the 2xclient from your applications menu and you are good to go !! (I hope)

BTW jump from your 2x RDP session (remote desktop) to your own desktop with keyboard shortcut windows-alt-m

Comment: I managed to fix the dependencies using this, but now it just segfaults when I run it :( Any further clues?

Answer (score 0):

According to the 2X website, there is no official package for 64 bit systems. You might be able to install from source following these steps ([source](http://www.2x.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4065#p13264)):

- Install ia32-libs

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
  ```

  I am not sure how this works on Ubuntu, but on Debian if you get this error:

  ```
  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-i386 but it is not installable
  E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
  ```

  You will need to run `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` and then install `ia32-libs` again.
- Download the 2X source code and extract it:

  ```
  mkdir 2XClient
  cd 2XClient
  wget http://2x.com/downloads/AppServer-LoadBalancer/2XClient.tar.bz2
  tar xvvjf 2XClient.tar.bz2
  ```
- Run the install script (in the `2XClient` directory):

  ```
  sudo ./opt/2X/Client/scripts/install.sh
  ```

Comment: Nope, it does not work

# sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
dpkg: error: unknown option --add-architecture

Comment: @user217816, Ah yes Ubuntu have removed ia32-libs and replaced it with multiarch, sorry. Have a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/107249/85695) thread.